# No me funciona el ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll-view, android.studio

Pues, tengo una vista personalizada con un `ScrollView` que solo debe mover el valor de un `TextView` pero por algún motivo no funcia. No se desliza ni nada.

`Layout` personalizado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/tmoBg">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvtituloLectu"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLectuProtadaSeleccion"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAutorLectu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/negro"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGenerosLectus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/negro"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tvSinopsisLectu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Adaptador:**

```
public class LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases;
    private Context context;

    public LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador(ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases, Context context) {
        this.lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases = lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vista_seleccion_lectulandia, parent, false);
        return new LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase lectuPrincipalClase = this.lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases.get(position);
        holder.titulo.setText(lectuPrincipalClase.getTitulo());
        holder.autor.setText(lectuPrincipalClase.getAutor());
        holder.generos.setText(lectuPrincipalClase.getGeneros());
        holder.sinopsis.setText(lectuPrincipalClase.getSinopsis());
        Picasso.get().load(lectuPrincipalClase.getImgUrl()).into(holder.portada);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView titulo, autor, generos, sinopsis;
        ImageView portada;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            portada = view.findViewById(R.id.ivLectuProtadaSeleccion);
            titulo = view.findViewById(R.id.tvtituloLectu);
            autor = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAutorLectu);
            generos = view.findViewById(R.id.tvGenerosLectus);
            sinopsis = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSinopsisLectu); //este es el valor que quiero que sea scrolleable
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            sinopsis.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> newList) {
        lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases = new ArrayList<>();
        lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> items) {
        this.lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClases = items;
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class LectulandiaSeleccion extends AppCompatActivity {
    private long id;
    AdView adView;
    Button btn;
    private DownloadManager downloadManager;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador lectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador;
    private ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClaseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lectulandia_seleccion);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvLEctuSeleccion);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DEscargarLEctulandia);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        lectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador = new LectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador(lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClaseArrayList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(lectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador);

        BuscandoDato buscandoDato = new BuscandoDato();
        buscandoDato.execute();

        bannerBookSearh();
    }

    private class BuscandoDato extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> items) {
            super.onPostExecute(items);
            //Actualizar información
            lectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.updateData(items);
            lectulandiaSeleccionLibroAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClaseArrayList.clear();
            String datoUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            String datoImagen = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagen");
            final String datoTitulo = getIntent().getStringExtra("titulo");

            Log.d("", "doInBackground: "+ datoUrl + "-" + datoImagen + "-" + datoTitulo);
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(datoUrl).get();
                Elements data = doc.select("div>.content-area");
                for (Element e : data) {
                    String autor = e.getElementById("autor").select("a").text();
                    String generos = e.getElementById("genero").select("a").text();
                    String sinopsis = e.getElementById("sinopsis").select("span").text();
                    String linkPdf = "";
                    if(e.getElementById("downloadContainer").select("a").size() > 0){
                        linkPdf = e.getElementById("downloadContainer").select("a").get(1).attr("href");
                        Log.d("", "doInBackground: "+ linkPdf);
                        final String finalLinkPdf1 = linkPdf;
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.lectulandia.co"+finalLinkPdf1));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClaseArrayList.add(new LectulandiaSeleccionItemsClase(datoTitulo, datoImagen, autor,
                                generos, sinopsis, linkPdf));
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return lectulandiaSeleccionItemsClaseArrayList;
        }
    }

    private void bannerBookSearh(){
        MobileAds.initialize(LectulandiaSeleccion.this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) { }
        });
        adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adViewLectuSeleccion);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        LectulandiaSeleccion.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Añado un GIF para que vean:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno sabe como solucionarlo? Estuve leyendo y probando de distintas maneras pero nada ha cambiado

Comment: Por qué tienes un linearlayout para cada elemento?

Comment: Por malos hábitos o costumbres @Benito-B

Comment: Ese código es el correcto para el funcionamiento de un Scroll, debería de estar funcionando. Te consulto, el textView tvSinopsisLectu ha generado contenido como para que este scrollview sea necesario? 

Sete el tvSinopsisLectu o inserta un text largo y cuéntame

Comment: Tal cual, tiene un texto muy largo por lo que debería funcionar pero no es el caso @YamilLazzari

Comment: Es raro, acabo de probarlo en android studio y si funciona ese scroll

Comment: y cual es ese valor?

Comment: No acabo de entender que quieres hacer.....¿Quieres que el valor del textview se mueva dentro de él? ¿O quieres que se mueva el textview con el valor a medida que mueves las barras del scrollview?

Comment: Claro, pero supongo que tiene que ver con el hecho de que este `layout` es para el adaptador y que por eso no funciona bien @YamilLazzari

Comment: es un valor que viene cargado desde el dato de una página de internet @Elenasys

Comment: Lo segundo, quiero explicarlo un poco mejor pero no encuentro las palabras adecuadas, disculpa @iqanansoft

Comment: He actualizado el código con un `GIF` para que sea más descriptivo lo que quiero

Comment: Prueba con un nested scrollview, puede que el cardview este interumpiendo o algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solucionalo con estas lineas de codigo

```
<ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"  android:fillViewport="true" >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSinopsisLectu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>
                </ScrollView>
```

creo que el problema era del tamaño del scrollview cuando le colocas una unidad absoluta de 400 en la altura, si le dices  en el scrollview con el

```
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

y el

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

el scrollview ocupara toda la pantalla que deje libre la imagen, y el "tittle".....

ademas recomiendo el android:fillViewport="true" para que el textview en el interior del scrollview se expanda correctamente en el scrollview.

por cierto no le pongas margenes en el texview que hay en el interior del scrollview, o sino podrias conseguir que el texto se corte con el scrollvidew, tampoco te recomiendo que uses en el textview un padding, pero si lo haces ten mucho cuidado que el scrollview no te corte el texto por arriba o por abajo

Comment: Pues, funcionó una vez. Le puse color al `TextView` y dejó de funcionar. Quité el color y no volvió a funcionar el scroll jajaja

Comment: Ahora q veo tu codigo tienes el width como warpcontent en el linear y en el scroll matchparent , lo cual es incoherente. Para problemas de layout mejor usa el layoutinspector para ver sus tamaños,como se ven ,etc. en tiempo real.

Comment: si , en verdad el linearlayout que contiene el scrollview no tiene mucho sentido , ya que el propio scrollview ya hace de contenedor...., por lo tanto yo traspasaria todas las propiedades del linearlayout que hace de contenedor al scrollview, y dejaria al scrollview libre sin linearlayout, Por cierto, añadirle color de fondo al textview o al scrollview no deberia afectar al funcionamiento del scroll, revisa que no tengas alguna etiqueta mal cerrada o unas dobles comillas mal colocadas